# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rtree'

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror

I'm getting this error message.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rtree'

I use Python 3.11.4 in the anaconda environment on Windows, and I have used both rtree 1.0.1 and 1.2.0, and both show the same error message.
It says rtree is already imported, but how can I fix it? I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you install Rtree via pip or Conda?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I did both  <pip install Rtree> and <conda install conda-forge::rtree> and rtree 1.2.0 is installed in the list!

Comment: Importing rtree from Command Prompt to python works well, but when I try to import it from code running in pycharm IDE, this error appears.

Comment: Then it sounds like a problem in pycharm. I never used pycharm before so I can't really help, but it should be because pycharm isn't using the correct version of python (the one in your environment I assume)